# How to show Product vendor dashboard pages on front end instead of back-end in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We are developing a e-commerce shopping site in which Product vendors can be add and manage their products from front end. We used Woocommerce, Product vendor, WP-User-Frontend-master etc plugin.We could manage products add/edit only in the front end. But the issue is that it is not able to show the product vendor's dashbord on front end. It is availabe from the admin side only. Is it possible to show it on front end or any url routing to route the url admin.php?page='some-thing'(related to vendor dashbord) as without 'wp-admin/admin.php' ?

Answer (score 0):

this plugin is more helpful https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-vendors/. 
I use it together with
http://wedevs.com/plugin/wp-user-frontend-pro/ 
and
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Much can be achieved with this combination